GUI errors after wake up system (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS)
I have a laptop with a 2.5K display and a Full HD monitor connected by HDMI.
I'm having a bit of trouble after the operating system wakes up! Basically, my laptop is asleep and then I try to enable it again. I pass a password and I see a desktop interface, but all the user interfaces have a random resolution, some windows without title bars, the Dock Panel not rendered, and the wallpaper lost (only a black screen). Sometimes the second monitor doesn't seem to want to play ball. Other times it works, but the resolution settings are lost.
I've also noticed something really interesting. When I logout and login again, everything works perfectly!
I'd be really grateful if anyone can help me with this!
I've tried using the default Nvidia driver 550 (which I tested) and also the Nvidia driver 530 (which I also tested), but unfortunately neither of them helped.
I'd love to know if you could help me with the Settings application.

I've set the built-in display to 1920x1200 (60Hz, scale 100%)
I've set the Iiyama North America 24" 2560x1440 (100Hz, scale 100%)

System Details Report

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              TIMI A30
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-11300H × 8
Graphics:                                    Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
Graphics 1:                                  NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3050 Ti Laptop GPU
Disk Capacity:                               (null)

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            XMATG5T0P0606
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-41-generic


After a few days of use and regular system updates, the problem went away by itself. I believe that this problem is not relevant, and does not require any actions on the part of the user except for regular system updates via apt get update and apt get upgrade

I would try upping my swap memory or checking if I have proper swap at all.

Make the swap file:

The following command is going to make a "swap filesystem" inside your fresh swap file.
mkswap /swap

How to bring up on boot:

To make sure that your new swap space is activated while booting up computer, you should add it to the filesystem configuration file /etc/fstab. Add it to the end of the file. This is recommended because other filesystems (at least one that contains a swap file) must be mounted in read-write mode before we can access any files.
Add this line to /etc/fstab
/swap none swap sw 0 0
Or use uuid with 'blkid' command and swap location.
UUID=598d9135-e58e-456e-b95d-af6eab11c264 none swap sw 0 0

Activate:

You can either reboot your computer or activate the new swap file by hand with the following command:
swapon /swap

Increasing Swap size through partition:

If your swap partition can be expanded into adjacent unallocated space then use gparted. If such space is not available, perhaps because your active (booted) partition is using all the non-swap space, then gparted will not allow you to decrease the size of the active partition in order to create unallocated space. In this case you can re-install Ubuntu in order to create a larger swap space.

swap partition size is a same with RAM size and I think  it's not a trouble.

Also after few days and some updates, situation is match better. Last 2 days I didn't get errors of current type
